# How to plot 24 hour for 365

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I plot time series data hourly so that x-axis is 1:24. If I hav let's say one year of data so 365 days and 8000+ rows?

Tried with `ggplot2` but didn't get it to work.

head looks like this

```
Value            DateTime
1   104 2018-01-01 01:00:00
2   104 2018-01-01 02:00:00
3   108 2018-01-01 03:00:00
4   106 2018-01-01 04:00:00
5   117 2018-01-01 05:00:00
6   166 2018-01-01 06:00:00

And Tail
   Value            DateTime
8754 160.10 2018-12-31 19:00:00
8755 156.11 2018-12-31 20:00:00
8756 139.11 2018-12-31 21:00:00
8757 112.11 2018-12-31 22:00:00
8758  96.10 2018-12-31 23:00:00
8759  90.11 2019-01-01 00:00:00
```

Here is an image what I'm trying to achieve

[image]

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: I tried similary that was done on my link. ```ggplot(data = df1, aes(y = kWh,x=rep(1:24,365),group=date(DateTime))) +
  stat_smooth(method="loess",se=FALSE,span=0.2,geom="line",alpha=0.1) +
  labs(x = "24 hour period of day")```

Comment: This gives me "aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data" error

Comment: You should really try to post the complete code but from what I see you only plot one line (loess). Try `geom_line(aes(group = date))`. This will hopefully gives you the lines.

Comment: You're more likely to get useful responses if you create a reproducible example. For instance just create a sample dataset and then what you tried. Just give the first and last lines of a data set and picture is not enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about having time of the day and date as seperate variables? You can use the package `hms` to do this.

```
timeOfDay <- as.hms(df$DateTime)
date      <- as.Date(df$DateTime)
```

Now, you can use `timeOfDay` on the x-axis and `date` as your grouping aesthetics.

This works for me:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = timeOfDay, y = value)) +
  geom_line(aes(group = date))
```